# Summing and Averaging values from multiple files in Python

Tags: python, addition, mean

I have a question regarding outputting in Python.

I have the following 3 files as input data:

#### File A

```
abc with-1-rosette-n    2
abc with-1-tyre-n   1
abc with-1-weight-n 2
```

#### File B

```
def with-1-rosette-n 1
def with-1-tyre-n   2
def about-bit-n 1
```

#### File C

```
ghi with-1-rosette-n  2
ghi as+n-produce-v   1
ghi then-damage-v  1
```

I first tried to create a script in which I would consider the sum of the values (Col 3) of the intersection of Col 2.

This works fine - outputs all lines properly.

I tried to modify the script to consider the mean of the values of Col 3 of the intersection of Col 2 and this is where I run into trouble.

Basically, the script does not output the lines of the intersection.

#### Script A

```python
def sumVectors(classA_infile, classB_infile, outfile):

        class_dictA = {}

        with open(classA_infile, "rb") as opened_infile_A:
                for line in opened_infile_A:
                        items = line.split()
                        classA, feat, valuesA = items[:3]
                        class_dictA[feat] = float(valuesA)


        class_dictB = {}

        with open(classB_infile, "rb") as opened_infile_B:
                for line in opened_infile_B:
                        items = line.split()
                        classB, feat, valuesB = items[:3]
                        class_dictB[feat] = float(valuesB)

        with open(outfile, "wb") as output_file:
                for key in class_dictA:
                        if key in class_dictB:
                                weight = (class_dictA[key] + class_dictB[key])/2
                                outstring = "\t".join([classA + "-" +  classB, key, str(weight)])
                                print outstring
                        else:
                                weight = class_dictA[key]
                                outstring = "\t".join([classA + "-" +  classB, key, str(weight)])
                output_file.write(outstring + "\n")

                for key in class_dictB:
                        if key not in class_dictA:
                                weight = class_dictB[key]
                                outstring = "\t".join([classA + "-" + classB, key, str(weight)])
                                output_file.write(outstring + "\n")
```

When I try to incorporate a third file: I run into a key issue. Here, I am trying to see if a key in File C is also in files A and B, if so, we take the average of those three files. In this case, it is giving me a Key Error, just when it enters the  first `if` block, so I am having a difficult time solving this problem.

Here is the example of the script for considering 3 files.

#### Script B

```python
def sumVectors(classA_infile, classB_infile, classC_infile, outfile):

        class_dictA = {}

        with open(classA_infile, "rb") as opened_infile_A:
                for line in opened_infile_A:
                        items = line.split()
                        classA, feat, valuesA = items[:3]
                        class_dictA[feat] = float(valuesA)


        class_dictB = {}

        with open(classB_infile, "rb") as opened_infile_B:
                for line in opened_infile_B:
                        items = line.split()
                        classB, feat, valuesB = items[:3]
                        class_dictB[feat] = float(valuesB)

        class_dictC = {}

        with open(classC_infile, "rb") as opened_infile_C:
                for line in opened_infile_C:
                        items = line.split()
                        classC, feat, valuesC = items[:3]
                        class_dictC[feat] = float(valuesC)

        with open(outfile, "wb") as output_file:
                for key in class_dictC:
                        if key in class_dictA and class_dictB:
                                weight = (class_dictA[key] + class_dictB[key]+ class_dictC[key])/3
                                outstring = "\t".join([classA + "-" +  classB + "-" +  classC, key, str(weight)])
                                print outstring
                        else:
                                weight = class_dictC[key]
                                outstring = "\t".join([classA + "-" +  classB + "-" +  classC,  key, str(weight)])
                                output_file.write(outstring + "\n")
```

In the case of Script A, the desired output would be:

(where we consider the mean of the common element in Col 2):

```
abc-def with-1-rosette-n    1.5
abc-def with-1-tyre-n   1
abc-def with-1-weight-n 2
def with-1-tyre-n   2
def about-bit-n 1
```

and in the case of Script B, the desired output would be:

File B
(where we consider the mean of common element of all 3 files in Col 2):

```
abc-def-ghi with-1-rosette-n    1.667
abc-def-ghi with-1-tyre-n   1.5
abc-def-ghi with-1-weight-n 2
abc-def-ghi with-1-rosette-n 1.5
abc-def-ghi about-bit-n 1
abc-def-ghi as+n-produce-v   1
abc-def-ghi then-damage-v  1
```

Can anyone help me see where I am going wrong, and I am unsure of the best pythonic route to solve it...
Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be showing the union of column2 for each file, not the intersection (union = all values which occur in any of the files, intersection = only values which occur in *all* of the files). Which is correct?

Comment: The first script outputs `abc-def with-1-tyre-n   1.5` `abc-def with-1-rosette-n        1.5` for File A and File B. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Aside: if you're actually doing this because you need the results, then you should look at a library like [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org), which makes performing grouping operations on data much easier.  If you're doing this for learning purposes, carry on. :^)

Comment: @HughBothwell I would like to output the union however, the average of the values of those common values in each of the files.

Comment: @TomFenech I want to output all of the lines of each file (as hughbothell corrected me above, therefore the union), considering the average of the values of those elements in common in col. 2 and the simple value of all other lines of the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Because you are looking for a union of files, we can treat
#  the input data as a simple concatenation of all input files;
# If you were after intersection, we would have to deal with
#  each input file separately.
def chain_from_files(*filenames):
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname, "rb") as inf:
            for line in inf:
                yield line

# get the key and all related data for each line
def get_item(line):
    row = line.split()
    return row[1], (row[0], int(row[2]))    # <= returns a tuple ('abc', 2)

# iterate through the input,
# collect a list of related values for each key
def collect_items(lines, get_item):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for line in lines:
        key, value = get_item(line)
        result[key].append(value)
    return result

# make an output-string for each key
# and its list of related values
def show_item(key, values):
    classes, nums = zip(*values)          # <= unpacks the tuples
    classes = '-'.join(sorted(set(classes)))
    average = float(sum(nums)) / len(nums)
    return "{} {} {}\n".format(classes, key, average)

def main():
    lines = chain_from_files(classA_infile, classB_infile, classC_infile)
    data  = collect_items(lines, get_item)

    with open(outputfile, "wb") as outf:
        for key,value in data.items():
            outf.write(show_item(key, value))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which gives as output

```
ghi then-damage-v 1.0
abc-def with-1-tyre-n 1.5
abc-def-ghi with-1-rosette-n 1.66666666667
ghi as+n-produce-v 1.0
abc with-1-weight-n 2.0
def about-bit-n 1.0
```

Comment: This approach not only solves my problem in more ways than one, by handling N number of files, but it also does it in an extremely efficient and faster way than how I was structuring the script.